# How can you record gameplay from both screens on the Nintendo DS?

Tags: nintendo-ds

My question is how can you record game-play from both screens on the Nintendo DS?
Not the 3DS

Comment: By "record", do you mean taking a screenshot, or a video? In either case, I don't know of any way other than use a camera (or 2) to capture the screens. But I doubt that's what you're looking for.